# Create Outlook 2007/2003 add-in in Visual Studio 2012 Professional

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, outlook-2007-addin

Is there any way to create add-in for Outlook 2007/2003 in Visual Studio 2012 (C#)?
So far I found that it should be possible and I just need to remove references from build-in 2010 add-in. Also tried to download some packages for older VS without success. After many attempts, during adding .dll file to Outlook 2007, I am still receiving error, that it is not add-in for Outlook 2007. 
After all, I doubt a lot that I can do some add-in for old Outlook 2003 if I am not able to do it for 2007. It would enough for this time to force 2007 add some add-in with only MessageBox on startup.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this library [NetOffice](http://netoffice.codeplex.com/). I'm using it and is very good.

Even if it does not fits your needs you can dig a little in the code and try to understand how they do it. They have nice examples.

BTW, If you are using VS express edition you cannot develop Office add-ins without a library like NetOffice.